# How can I force my Python unit tests to print tracebacks after error logs?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7

I'm attempting to unit test some complex network stuff, and every time there's an error, my networking libraries output hundreds of lines of log messages. The only thing I'm interested in is the actual traceback of the error, but I have to scroll up through all those log messages to see the traceback.

Is there any way to force Python's unittest module to output tracebacks after logs instead of the other way around?

For example, I currently see the following:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: my_test (tests.MyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_code_file.py", line 39, in my_function
    my_module.my_function()
  File "my_code_file.py", line 78, in my_function
    raise Exception("My exception here")
Exception: My exception here
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
<<< hundreds of lines of logs from networking libraries/wiretraces/etc>>>
<<< hundreds of lines of logs from networking libraries/wiretraces/etc>>>
<<< hundreds of lines of logs from networking libraries/wiretraces/etc>>>
<<< hundreds of lines of logs from networking libraries/wiretraces/etc>>>
<<< hundreds of lines of logs from networking libraries/wiretraces/etc>>>
-------------------- >> end captured logging << --------------------
```

I would like to see something like this so I can see my errors quickly after running my tests:

```
======================================================================
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------
<<< hundreds of lines of logs from networking libraries/wiretraces/etc>>>
<<< hundreds of lines of logs from networking libraries/wiretraces/etc>>>
<<< hundreds of lines of logs from networking libraries/wiretraces/etc>>>
<<< hundreds of lines of logs from networking libraries/wiretraces/etc>>>
<<< hundreds of lines of logs from networking libraries/wiretraces/etc>>>
-------------------- >> end captured logging << --------------------
ERROR: my_test (tests.MyTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_code_file.py", line 39, in my_function
    my_module.my_function()
  File "my_code_file.py", line 78, in my_function
    raise Exception("My exception here")
Exception: My exception here
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `logging` module?

Honestly I am not sure exactly what function you would use for best results.

However, there is `logging.exception`

**EX:**

```
import logging

try:
    print blah

except Exception, e:
    logging.exception("\n\n !!!!!! \n\n  {} \n\n !!!!!! \n\n".format(e))
```

**Output on that Exception arising is nicely visible:**

```
ERROR:root:

 !!!!!! 

  name 'blah' is not defined 

 !!!!!! 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-39-99d79696f33a>", line 2, in <module>
    print blah
NameError: name 'blah' is not defined
```